# Listen to LongPressGesture on UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, swift4

I want to attach a simple `long press` on a single UITabBarItem. Is this possible in `swift 4`? I have tried like below but the UITabBarItem doesn't have the event members that I can implement[image]
The `uiTabBar` is the outlet. I've seen also that I can use a [UITabBarDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbardelegate) but I haven't got it to work.
The longTap function's signature looks like:

```
@objc func longTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){}
```

Comment: i dont think, you can add gesture recognizer to a tabbaritem

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. I had to place a button on top of it. See how I did it on my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up placing a `UIButton` on top of the `UITabBarItem` I wanted to attach the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to. I prepared the button using the function below:

```
 //Declare the button 
 let uiTabBar = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)

func setupMiddleButton() {
        // Create image
        let africaIcon = UIImage(named: "ic_africa")

        let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
        let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
        uiTabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBarItemSize.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
        var menuButtonFrame = uiTabBar.frame
        menuButtonFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        menuButtonFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
        uiTabBar.frame = menuButtonFrame
        uiTabBar.setImage(africaIcon, for: UIControlState.normal)
        //uiTabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.view.addSubview(uiTabBar)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

To attach the events, I did the following:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(normalTap(_:)))
                tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
                uiTabBar.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
                let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longTap(_:)))
                uiTabBar.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
                //Set default tab
                self.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Selector methods are shown below:

```
@objc func normalTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
    self.selectedIndex = 1;
}

@objc func longTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
    print("Long tap")
    if sender.state == .ended {
        print("UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded")
        //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
        //This is when the long event is triggered
    }
    else if sender.state == .began {
        print("UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.")
        //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
    }
}
```

The 'TabBar' at the middle was created with the events I wanted.[image]